# object mail is not a member of package views.html error in IntelliJ Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to build a Scala (2.13) project using sbt in IntelliJ. I know that there are no problems in the dependencies or source code since my colleagues are using it. I exactly have the following error :

```
 object mail is not a member of package views.html
    val bodyHtml = views.html.mail.auth
```

I tried several stuff such as : invalidate the cache or  delete **.idea** folder but nothing seems to be working until now. I don't think it is a JVM version but just for completeness I am using JVM 17.

Comment: Does it work if you compile using **sbt** directly?

Comment: Do you use play or twirl?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently for my case doing the following commands works out:

```
sbt clean
sbt compile
```

Then I do not see any errors.